# Can we use JMeter to test Oracle ERP suite?

Tags: oracle, performance, testing, jmeter, load

I have to do performance/load testing of Oracle EBS application. Can I use Jmeter for the same?

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple applications in Oracle ERP based on different underlying technologies, at least:

- Oracle Forms (no)
- Oracle Siebel (yes)
- Oracle JD Edwards (yes)
- Oracle People Soft (yes)
- Oracle Hyperion Financial Management (yes)
- Oracle ADF (yes)

For those marked (yes) , it is possible since it's textual format to run load test. But you need to do correlation which can take some time.
There are [commercial JMeter plugins](https://ubikloadpack.com/) that ease load testing of such technologies.

For the ones based on Oracle Forms, protocol is binary, OOTB it will be impossible to load test them realistically.

Disclaimer : We are provider of the solution referenced.